# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I keep receiving an error of `*AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'*` when trying to run the below code. Tried testing with `data_sets.head(`) and received the error *`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'head'*`

```
dataDir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Final/dataQ2/' # Directory with input files
trainFile = 'q2train.csv' # Training examples
labelFile = 'q2label.csv' # Test label
validFile = 'q2valid.csv' # Valid Files

data_sets = {
      'train' : train,
      'label' : label,
      'valid' : valid}

def get_data(data_set_name, test_prop=0.2, seed=2019):
  """returns data for training, testing, and data characteristics"""
  data = data_sets[data_set_name]
  X, y = data.data, data.target
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                      test_size=test_prop, 
                                                      random_state=seed)
  nF = X.shape[1] # number of features
  nC = len(np.unique(y)) # number of classes
  nTrain, nTest = len(y_train), len(y_test)
  return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, nF, nC, nTrain, nTest

for name in data_set:
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, nF, nC, nTrain, nTest = get_data(name)
```

Assistance is appreciated, sorry in advance if this is a dumb question.

Comment: `data_sets` is a `dict`, so it makes sense `head` wouldn't work. Would `data.head()` work? what is `data` at that point?

Comment: Unless you have a column called `data`, it is a normal behavior. It looks like you are confused with the `bundle` from `sklearn.datasets`?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what I am doing. I am trying to prep the data to be run through different machine learning models.

Comment: The first column in train.csv and valid.csv contains values of the output binary variable Y. The first column in label.csv contains an identifier id. The next 200 columns in each file contain values of input features X1, …, X200.

Comment: `data` is a pandas dataframe. Pandas dataframes do not have a `data` attribute. That is what your first error is telling you.  What are you trying to get from the dataframe? This page might be helpful for you. It lists all of the attributes and methods you can call on a dataframe. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score -1):

i come across the same question。
i solved this bug by updating my pandas from 1.0.1 to 1.0.5

Comment: better as a comment